# Error when trying to install arm-elf-binutils using MacPorts

Tags: installation, mac, mac-osx

I'm trying to install arm-elf-binutils on my Mac using MacPorts.

I get the following error:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for arm-elf-gcc
--->  Dependencies to be installed: arm-elf-binutils
--->  Building arm-elf-binutils
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install arm-elf-binutils
Log for arm-elf-binutils is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_cross_arm-elf-binutils/arm-elf-binutils/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: arm-elf-binutils
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see
```

Yes, I am using sudo.

Here's the log: (I put it on pastie.org because it's really big.)

http://pastie.org/3120533

I have xcode and the ios/mac toolchain installed.

Comment: libintl.h is missing, what is the output of `port provides /opt/local/include/libintl.h`?

Comment: port provides /opt/local/include/libintl.h
/opt/local/include/libintl.h is provided by: gettext

Comment: Good start, that is the output I would expect. Assuming it is not installed, get gettext installed first. The file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_cross_arm-elf-binutils/arm-elf-binutils/work/binutils-2.21.52.0.2/bfd/sysdep.h is referencing libintl.h, after installing gettext, ensure /opt/local/include/libintl.h exists.

Comment: You may need to fix sysdep.h or create a link to the actual libintl.h file.

Comment: It is already installed an I have the libintl.h file in /opt/local/include/libintl.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/libintl.h /usr/include/.
```

then run the build again